# what's wrong with this single PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Here the thing, other PDO works well, but this one doesn't. I have tried with

```
execute(array(':t'=>$table));
```

with no success. Ideas?.

```
public function __construct($table){
        try{
                $pdocnx = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sigcat",'root','');
                $stmt = $pdocnx->prepare('select * from sigcat.:t');
                $stmt->bindParam(':t', urldecode($table), PDO::PARAM_STR,45);
                $stmt->execute();
                $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                var_dump($row);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   

    }
```

I got many records in 'supplies' but it returns array(0) { }. I'm getting the 'table' parameter with $_GET['table']. No exceptions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind table names, only values.

Maintain a list of valid names and ensure the string is present in the valid list.

If you can't build a list of valid names, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks. With a switch + mysql_list_tables I will accomplish it then.

Answer (score -1):

You can't bind tables, so you can do a sneaky trick like this:

```
public function myFunction($table){
    $st = "SELECT FROM `" . $table ."` ..some sql";
    $statement->prepare($st);
    $statement->execute();

}
```

Hope this helps.